# Using swift built in partition to manage elements in an array

Tags: swift, partition

iOS 14, Swift 5.x

I watched this excellent WWDC from 2018

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/223/

And I wrote a shapes editor... and have been trying to use partition as Dave in the video says you should. I got the first three to work, but the last one I had to use a loop- cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to work with partition.

Can someone see how I might do this?

The first method moves the selected object to the end of the list, works perfectly.

```
func bringToFrontEA() {
let subset = objects.partition(by: { $0.selected })
let selected = objects[subset...]
let unselected = objects[..<subset]
let reordered = unselected + selected
objects = Array(reordered)
}
```

The second method moves the selected object to the front of the list. Works prefectly.

```
func sendToBackEA() {
let subset = objects.partition(by: { !$0.selected })
let selected = objects[subset...]
let unselected = objects[..<subset]
let reordered = unselected + selected
objects = Array(reordered)
}
```

The third method moves the element just one element back in the list. Works perfectly.

```
func sendBackEA() {
if let i = objects.firstIndex(where: { $0.selected }) {
  if i == 0 { return }
  let predecessor = i - 1
  let shapes = objects[predecessor...].partition(by: { !$0.selected })
  let slice = objects[predecessor...]
  let row = objects[..<predecessor]
  
  let selected = Array(slice[..<shapes])
  let unselected = Array(slice[shapes...])
  
  objects = row + selected + unselected
}
}
```

The last method moves the element forward in the list, works perfectly... but unlike the other methods it will not scale as described in the WWDC video.

```
func bringForwardEA() {
let indexes = objects.enumerated().filter { $0.element.selected == true }.map{$0.offset}
for i in indexes {
    if objects[i+1].unused {
      return
    }
    objects.swapAt(i+1, i)
  }
}
```

Objects is an array of shapes with a property indicating if it is selected or not. I want to exchange the loop in the last method by using a partition as I did in the first three. It needs to work for one or more selected shapes.

Comment: Can you describe what each of the methods are supposed to do? Are they actually working as intended right now and you just don't want to use the loop?

Comment: Also, what is this `unused` property that you are checking in `bringForwardEA`? You didn't check this in `sendBackEA`, so why are you checking it in `bringForwardEA`?

Comment: @Sweeper Edited Question, put more detail

Comment: I just watched a few minutes of the WWDC and I think I understand now. `bringForwardEA` is supposed to make the _last_ selected shape go back one index, and move all the other selected elements before the last selected shape. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the WWDC video, it appears that what you are calling `sendBackEA` is what WWDC calls `bringForward`, and what you are calling `bringForwardEA` is what WWDC calls `sendBack`.

Just like how you move the *first* selected element *forward* one index (index decreases) in `sendBackEA`, then move all the other selected elements to immediately *after* that first selected element. `bringForwardEA` should do the reverse: move the *last* selected element *backward* one index (index increases), then move all the other selected elements to immediately *before* the last selected element. (See circa 19:10 in the video)

You seem to have confused yourself by trying to increase the indices of all the selected index by 1. This obviously cannot be done with a partition in general.

Also note that `partition(by:)` already modifies the collection, you don't need to get each partition, then recombine.

Your 4 methods can be written like this:

```
func bringToFrontEA() {
    objects.partition(by: { $0.selected })
}

func sendToBackEA() {
    objects.partition(by: { !$0.selected })
}

func sendBackEA() {
    if let i = objects.indices.first(where: { objects[$0].selected }) {
      if i == 0 { return }
      let predecessor = i - 1
      objects[predecessor...].partition(by: { !$0.selected })
    }
}

func bringForwardEA() {
    if let i = objects.indices.last(where: { objects[$0].selected }) {
        if i == objects.indices.last { return }
        let successor = i + 1
        objects[...successor].partition(by: { !$0.selected })
    }
}
```

Notice the symmetry between `sendBackEA` and `bringForwardEA`.

Comment: One of the best answers I ever read on SO!!! Thank you Sweeper!